# Laravel Routing returns blank page

Tags: php, laravel, routes

to make it a bit short. I just made a registration form fully working with a controller, the routes and the view. Now I know it's common sense to use a Model for it and in the controller only call the method in the model. So i thought okay lets fix that. Now when I register an account I get a blank page. I bet the redirect is going wrong but I can't fix it maybe you can?

RegisterController.php

```
public function doRegister(){
    $user = new User();
    $user->doRegister();

}
```

User.php (model)

```
public function doRegister()
{
    // process the form here

    // create the validation rules ------------------------
    $rules = array(
        'username'             => 'required|unique:users',
        'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'         => 'required|min:5',
        'serial_key'            => 'required|exists:serial_keys,serial_key|unique:users'
    );
    // create custom validation messages ------------------
    $messages = array(
        'required' => 'The :attribute is important.',
        'email'  => 'The :attribute is not a legit e-mail.',
        'unique' => 'The :attribute is already taken!'
    );

    // do the validation ----------------------------------
    // validate against the inputs from our form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // check if the validator failed -----------------------
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        // get the error messages from the validator
        $messages = $validator->messages();

        // redirect our user back to the form with the errors from the validator
        return Redirect::to('/register')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password', 'password_confirm'));
    } else {
        // validation successful ---------------------------

        // our duck has passed all tests!
        // let him enter the database

        // create the data for our duck
        $duck = new User;
        $duck->username = Input::get('username');
        $duck->email = Input::get('email');
        $duck->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $duck->serial_key = Input::get('serial_key');


        // save our user

        $duck->save();

        // redirect with username ----------------------------------------

        return Redirect::to('/registered')->withInput(Input::old('username'));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make $user->doRegister(); a return statement

in your RegisterController you have to do

```
public function doRegister(){
$user = new User();
return $user->doRegister();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return Redirect::to('/registered')
            ->with('bill_no', Input::get('username'));
```

in the '/registered' controller,..
 use this

```
$username = Session::get("username");
```

above worked for me,...